# setTimeout and click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, settimeout

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rshownews").click(function() {
        window.setInterval(function() {ajaxselectrss($(this).attr("title"))}, 1000);
    });
});

 function ajaxselectrss(rssurlvar) {
  var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

 try{
  // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
  ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 } catch (e){
  // Internet Explorer Browsers
  try{
   ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  } catch (e) {
   try{
    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   } catch (e){
    // Something went wrong
    alert("Your browser broke!");
    return false;
   }
  }
 }
 // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
 ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){

   var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('news');
   ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
  }
 }



 //var rssurlvar = $(this).attr("title");
 var queryString = "rurl=" + rssurlvar;
 var urltofile = "rssget.php";
 ajaxRequest.open("POST", urltofile, true);
 ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", queryString.length);
 ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
 ajaxRequest.send(queryString); 

}
```

But the POST query is undefined.Why?

Comment: What are you trying to do? also your code is not correct.

Comment: I am trying to do this ,because I want to send an AJAX request to a file every second to define is there new content in the DB.

Comment: try `setInterval(function() {someFunc($(this).attr("title"));}, 1000);`

Comment: @sje397 - this WORKS!!! But the POST query is undefined

Comment: @Iam3r4370 - try using [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), and that should be a separate question - otherwise it makes all the other attempts to answer unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setInterval` can take a string or a function pointer. Passing a string containing '$(this)' won't work (because passing a string has the effect of the string being eval'd at call time).

So try:

```
var title = $(this).attr('title');
setInterval(function() {someFunc(title);}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code should look like this at least:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".rshownews").click(ajaxselectrss);
});

function ajaxselectrss() {
  //ajax function
}

setTimeout(ajaxselectrss, 1000);
```

For repeated task, use [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) instead.

Comment: @lam: remove quotes from `'someFunc($(this).attr("title"))'`, try `someFunc($(this).attr("title"))`

Comment: useless setInterval call (missing quotes around argument?)

Comment: Dont remove the double quotes from `"title"` just the single quotes wrapping your function.

Comment: unless someFunc returns a function, removing the quotes won't help. You need to pass a function to setInterval, not the result of one.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should use [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) rather than setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

You cant use `$(this)` in a setInterval, maybe something like this will work

```
var rshownews;
function someFunc(rssurlvar) {
  $('body').append('<br>'+rssurlvar);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".rshownews").click(function() {
        rshownews = $(this).attr("title");
        window.setInterval('someFunc(rshownews)',1000);
    });
});​
```

Edit with setInterval you need the var and function to be in the global scope, [demo](http://jsbin.com/idece3/)

Comment: code updated, you needed the function `someFunc` and var `rshownews` in the global scope